# how to show error message once in list view builder in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Here I am using List view builder to show my api response in lists and inside that list I am comparing one of the response with my static string variable and if the response and that variable matched it will show the api response and if it doesn't match then it will show error from text widget.

**This is my static string variable**

```
late String _valueName = 'All';
```

**And this is my List view**

```
ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: response.response.length,
                              itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                                return _valueName !=
                                        response.response[index].status
                                    ? const Center(
                                        child: Texts(texts: 'No Data'))
                                    : Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                            vertical: 8.0),
                                        child: GunasoContainer(
                                     
                                          date: response
                                              .response[index].created_at,
                                          grievancetype: response
                                              .response[index]
                                              .grievancetype!
                                              .title!,
                                          gunasoNum: response
                                              .response[index].grievance_no,
                                          status:
                                              response.response[index].status,
                                       
                              },
                            ),
```

now, the problem is the error message is displayed according to length of the response so error message is being displayed multiple times, as shown in picture below **so by any means Can i display the error message only once??**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make the `itemCount` return 1 when there is such error, like

```
itemCount: _valueName != response.response[0]?.status ? 1 : response.response.length,
```